# TypeError: when generating combinations with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I'm trying to implement the Apriori association rule mining algorithm. I switched to using generators to create the candidate itemset pairs. When I try to create the combinations, I get 'TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable'

here is an example of the orders dataframe

https://puu.sh/DdJSj/0b6401efac.png

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby, combinations
import pandas

#now we will use a generator instead of dicts to save memory
def generate_pairs(orders, k):
    #generate item list for order
    for id, order in groupby(orders, lambda x: x[0]):
        items = [item[0] for item in order]

    #generate pairs for each itemlist
    for pair in combinations(items, k):
        yield pair

def itemcount(iterable):
    if type(iterable) == pandas.core.series.Series:
        return iterable.value_counts().rename("count")
    else:
        return pandas.Series(Counter(iterable)).rename("count")
```

```
pair_generator = generate_pairs(orders, 2)
print(pair_generator)
pairs = itemcount(pair_generator).to_frame("count(AB)")
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cosco/PycharmProjects/untitled/finalp/final.py", line 183, in <module>
    rules = generate_rules(transactions, supp_percent)
  File "C:/Users/Cosco/PycharmProjects/untitled/finalp/final.py", line 80, in generate_rules
    pairs = itemcount(pair_generator).to_frame("count(AB)")
  File "C:/Users/Cosco/PycharmProjects/untitled/finalp/final.py", line 33, in itemcount
    print(type(pandas.Series(Counter(iterable)).rename("count")))
  File "C:\Users\Cosco\Miniconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 534, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Cosco\Miniconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 621, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
  File "C:/Users/Cosco/PycharmProjects/untitled/finalp/final.py", line 22, in generate_pairs
    for id, order in groupby(orders, lambda x: x[0]):
  File "C:/Users/Cosco/PycharmProjects/untitled/finalp/final.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    for id, order in groupby(orders, lambda x: x[0]):
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong? I understand that x should be an iterable, however when I debug, x is a single item_id

edit: generator works (incorrectly) when generate_pairs() is changed as follows:

```
def generate_pairs(orders, k):
    orders = orders.reset_index().values
    #generate item list for order
    for id, order in groupby(orders, lambda x: x[0]):
        itemlist = [item[1] for item in order]

    #generate pairs for each itemlist
    for pair in combinations(itemlist, k):
        yield pair
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that pandas `DataFrames` work like lists, but they don't.

You can modify your program as such:

```
def generate_pairs(orders, k):
    orders = orders.values.tolist()
    ...
```

But keep in mind you won't be able to access labels or formatting inside `generate_pairs`.

*Note*: You may be able to get away with `orders = orders.values` too - that will save you from `O(n)` copying data (from numpy to PyList) but may be problematic if you expect `orders`'s type to be exactly a list.

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks! (Also a pesky off-by-1 error)

[I'm pretty sure it's missing some combinations (and the count is incorrect), but at least I'm getting somewhere](https://puu.sh/DdNSX/af7d16184a.png)

Comment: @thiccomode You are resetting the value of `itemlist` every iteration of groupby. Create a list outside the loop, and append to it.